# Create immutable objects using Hashmap in Groocy

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have groovy class `Payment` where I have static method `payment` to create `Payment` using `HashMap`. This gives me nice flexibility in terms of what parameters I want to override in given context. It's super useful for testing purposes.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

class Payment {

    private final BigDecimal amount
    private final String currency
    private final LocalDateTime occurred

    Payment() {
        this.amount = null
        this.currency = null
        this.occurred = null
    }

    Payment(BigDecimal amount, String currency, LocalDateTime occurred) {
        this.amount = amount
        this.currency = currency
        this.occurred = occurred
    }

    static Payment payment(Map params = [:]) {
        def defaults = [
                amount  : 500.00,
                currency: 'EUR',
                occurred: LocalDateTime.now(),
        ]
        new Payment(defaults << params)
    }
}
```

Current problem with this class is whenever I call `payment` method, it returns `groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: amount for class: Payment`.

In order to make this working I have to break class immutability by removing `final` keywords.

Is there some way how to keep immutability and create objects using `Hashmap` in Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no map-c'tor, Groovy unrolls that operation into

```
def obj = new Payment()
obj.amount = map.amount
...
```

Which then gives you the error you are seeing.  Adding
a [`MapConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/MapConstructor.html)
annotation to your class should already fix that.  Yet there is an even
better annotation, that does that and much more:
[`Immutable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html).

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import java.time.Instant

@Immutable
class Payment {
    BigDecimal amount
    String currency
    Instant ts

    static Payment payment(Map params = [:]) {
        new Payment([amount: 500, currency: 'EUR', ts: Instant.now()] << params)
    }
}

println Payment.payment(amount: 42)
// → Payment(42, EUR, 2021-02-26T18:22:09.226109Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the tuple constructor from the factory method you have created, you can use getAt:

```
def m = defaults << params
new Payment(m['amount'], m['currency'], m['occurred'])
```

or skip the left shift and use params.getOrDefault('amount', 500g)

But you're better off using @Immutable